# Cover an image with black and reveal parts of the image using mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, image, drawing, layer

So I am creating a "Map Viewer" for a program I am working on. Basically I want to display a map and have it resize the image to fit in the grid. For this I am using Viewbox to hold the image and resize it. I was attempting to use this code to reveal the map but it does not center the circle on the mouse and it does not retain the revealed portions of the map (it ONLY reveals where the mouse is and not where it has been).

Here is the XAML:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="MapHolder" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="7" Margin="25,5,25,15">
                <Image x:Name="SelectedMap" Source="/wizard_dungeon.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" MouseMove="SelectedMap_MouseMove" >
                    <Image.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="None" >
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <Ellipse Width="400" Height="400" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Black"/>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <VisualBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="OpacityFilterTransform" X="1" Y="1"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </VisualBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Image.OpacityMask>
                </Image>

            </Viewbox>
```

And the code-behind:

```
private void SelectedMap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var position = e.GetPosition(this);
            var height = MapHolder.ActualHeight;
            var width = MapHolder.ActualWidth;
            // with the position values, interpolate a TranslateTransform for the opacity mask
            var transX = position.X / width;
            var transY = position.Y / height;
            OpacityFilterTransform.X = transX - 0.5;
            OpacityFilterTransform.Y = transY - 0.5;
        }
```

I want there to basically be a Image under a Black screen and I can erase the black screen to reveal the image in the areas I have erased.

Comment: I dont know if I would go with an opacity transform (granted I havent used them). 
I would personally go with drawing a black Rectangle, and then base on the mouse, and your dimensions of the circle you want to reveal, I would change the alpha channel of the Black Rectangle pixels within the circle.

Comment: Thank you for a response, where would I look for information on how to do that?